# bash - multiple if clauses. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm practicing writing small bash scripts. I have a habit of accidentally typing "teh" instead of "the". So now I want to start at a directory and go through all the files there to find how many occurrences of "teh" there are.

Here's what I have:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    for file in `find` ; do
     if [ -f "${file}" ] ; then
      for word in `cat "${file}"` ; do
       if [ "${word}" = "teh" -o "${word}" = "Teh" ] ; then
        echo "found one"
       fi    
      done
     fi
    done
```

When I run it, I get

```
    found one
    found one
    found one
    found one
    found one
    found one
    ./findTeh: line 6: [: too many arguments
```

Why am I getting too many arguments. Am I not doing the if statement properly?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, `-o` or `-a` test constructs are deprecated for -- almost certainly -- the reason the bug you're hitting here exists.

Comment: What is the value of `$word` when the error occurs?

Comment: I'd put money that it's something like `(`.

Comment: ...BTW, `for file in $(find); do` is itself very buggy -- won't ever work with files with spaces in their names.

Comment: `for word in $(cat "${file}"); do` is buggy too -- look what it does when your word is `*`.

Comment: ...actually, doesn't have to be `(`; could also be, say, `!`.

Comment: `grep -niwr teh .` gives you more and better output with *much* less code. In general, looping over all lines in a file in shell script is usually better avoided.

Comment: @tripleee, absolutely. I assumed that the OP was doing this as an exercise, but it might have been worth calling that out explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of `test` with more than three arguments is, per POSIX, not well-defined and deprecated. That's because variable arguments can be treated as logical constructs with meaning to the test command itself in that case.

Instead, use the following, which will work on all POSIX shells, not only bash:

```
if [ "$word" = teh ] || [ "$word" = Teh ]; then
  echo "Found one"
fi
```

...or, similarly, a case statement:

```
case $word in
  [Tt]eh) echo "Found one" ;;
esac
```

---

Now, let's look at [the actual standard underlying the `test` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

> >4 arguments:
>
> The results are unspecified.
>
> [OB XSI] [Option Start] On XSI-conformant systems, combinations of primaries and operators shall be evaluated using the precedence and associativity rules described previously. In addition, the string comparison binary primaries '=' and "!=" shall have a higher precedence than any unary primary. [Option End]

Note the `OB` flag: The use of a single `test` command with more than four arguments is **obsolete**, and is an optional part of the standard regardless (which not all shells are required to implement).

---

Finally, consider the following revision to your script, with various other bugs fixed (albeit using various bashisms, and thus not portable to all POSIX shells):

```
#!/bin/bash

# read a filename from find on FD 3
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename <&3; do
  # read words from a single line, as long as there are more lines
  while read -a words; do
    # compare each word in the most-recently-read line with the target
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do
      [[ $word = [Tt]eh ]] && echo "Found one"
    done
  done <"$filename"
done 3< <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Some of the details:

- By delimiting filenames with NULs, this works correctly with all possible filenames, including files with spaces or newlines in their names, which `for file in $(find)` does not.
- Quoted array expansion, ie. `for word in "${words[@]}"`, avoids glob expansion; with the old code, if `*` were a word in a file, then the code would subsequently be iterating over filenames in the current directory rather than over words in a file.
- Using `while read -a` to read in a single line at a time both avoids the aforementioned glob expansion behavior, and also acts to constrain memory usage (if very large files are in play).

Comment: What is the reason for using the `case` statement over `if [[ $word == [Tt]eh ]]`?

Comment: @BenjaminW., portability; I prefer to at least demonstrate POSIX-compliant practices where possible. That said, it would make sense to do the latter in the all-bashisms-all-the-time example at the end. :)

Comment: @BenjaminW., ...and edited appropriately; suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom to avoid this sort of problem is to add "x" on both sides of comparisons:

```
if [ "x${word}" = "xteh" -o "x${word}" = "xTeh" ] ; then
```

Comment: `==` isn't allowed in POSIX test; the only legal string comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: You should explain the problem that the `x` prefix solves.

Comment: Doing like that is more portable. "${FOO}" will not be exactly the same as the empty string in some implementations of Bash if FOO was not set, or is empty.

Comment: @Akira, untrue -- that's not the actual cause of the bug here; with the quotes in place, the unset/empty-string case is handled just fine for all POSIX-compliant shells, including every version of bash that exists. Your proposed fix *does* work, but it's not empty strings that it addresses; quoting correctly is itself enough to fix the empty-string case comprehensively.

Comment: @Akira, ...and as for `==` instead of `=`, many shells (albeit none of them bash) **don't work with `==`**, though the standard *requires* them to support `=`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, and try your code against dash or posh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, about ==, you are right. Will fix that. It's just what I feel is more common, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Akira, ...and if your goal is "more portable", using the `-o` argument to `test` (being, as it is, an optional XSI extension) isn't portable to begin with.